# Can I leave the Schengen area from another country other than the one I issued the visa from?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, finland

I have a Spanish visa type D for 115 days. I will spend the last week of my visa with a friend in Finland. Is it ok to return to my country from Finland directly or do I have to return to Spain first then travel from Spain to my country?

And I know I have the ability to visit the Schengen area with my student visa for 90 days within 180 days. Are the days I spent in Spain are calculated within the 90 days (as Spain is the country where I study and I already spent more than 90 days in it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 90 days are the time you can spend in other Schengen countries, excluding Spain. That's the point of D-visas: Staying longer than 90 days in one country and only incidentally in others. If Spain was included, the 115 days would be meaningless and it would never be possible to stay longer than three months with such a visa.

You can also leave through Finland, there is no requirement to leave through Spain. The only concern could be that Finnish border guards suspect you have actually been longer than 90 days *in Finland* (thus abusing your Spanish visa to reside there instead of Spain).

It's very unlikely to come up but if you are worried about it, you can keep some evidence that you have only been there for a week, things like a ticket from Spain to Finland, receipts or anything else proving your presence in Spain during the past 4 months, etc.